# How to integrate Jenkins with Generic repository in Artifactory via file specs?

Tags: jenkins, repository-pattern, artifactory

I am trying to upload a project to a **generic repository** in Artifactory while maintaining it's layout.
I am using the following specs in the **job configuration** to upload:

[image]

The specs upload the directory files **without** keeping the layout. Meaning all the files are taken from subdirectories and thrown to the repository in one place.

I tried adding the flag: **"flat": "false"** which is suppose to help maintain the directory structure(according to JFrog website) but when I use it:
`{
       "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "C:\TestForJenkins\WindowsApplication1\bin/",
      "target": "WindowsApplication1/",
      "recursive": "true", 
      "flat": "false"`     <<------------------- 
    `}
  ]
}`

**I get an error:**
`ERROR: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.UploadSpecHelper.stripFileNameFromPath(UploadSpecHelper.java:372)`

I can't find a way to use the flag **flat** and upload the files according to their layout in the bin directory.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have encountered this [Jira issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1010).
The fix for this Jira will be in the next Jenkins-Artifactory Plugin version.
In general, you can search the [JFrog Jira](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to see if you have encountered a known issue. Or take a look [here](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%29%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%27artifactory-plugin%27) and [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin).

All in all, without further info (i.e. full stacktrace + Jenkins version + Jenkins-Artifactory Plugin version) this does not look like a user error.

Hope it helps.